# How to get notified about new friends and removed friends using the Facebook API?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I need to implement a Facebook application in which a user registers with my application and I get the user's access_token with offline access.
How can I check who has removed the user from the user's friends and who has added the user as a new friend? How could I get it done using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be writing a cron job which uses the offline access to get friends details of each user and compare it with existing data and update the database. If you find any difficulty to get it done using offline access, you can do it while a user comes to the application. Such scripts can slow down your application and hence I am looking for cron job.

To optimize this, just get the friends details and write to a text file while the user comes to the application. Later run a cron job to compare the friends data in the text file with the database and make required updates.

Please let me know if this works for you

Comment: Great! feel free to contact me if you need any support in this section :)